# Unexpected difference of spsolve and solve

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to solve linear equations with varied sizes. Sometime the size may be 0 or 1 in which cases some errors will happen. For example,

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import solve
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
A1 = np.array([[1,2],[2,1]])
b1 = np.array([[1],[1]])
A2 = np.array([[1]])
b2 = np.array([[1]])
```

Some unexpected results will happen when calling spsolve or solve:

```
sage: solve(A1,b1)
array([[ 0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333]])
sage: solve(A2,b2)
array([[ 1.]])
sage: spsolve(A1,b1)
array([ 0.33333333,  0.33333333])
sage: spsolve(A2,b2)
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array
```

Notice that the call of "spsolve(A1,b1)" actually yields a row vector, is there anyway to force it to be a column vector? Also, the error in calling "spsolve(A2,b2)" is also very strange since the size of A1 and b1 are not zero.

Answer (score 1):

`spsolve` does not return an 2d array but a 1d vector.

Use `numpy.atleast_2d` to inflate the vector, e.g., in your example

```
In [10]: np.atleast_2d(spsolve(A1,b1)).T
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0.33333333],
       [ 0.33333333]])
```

and `.T` to get a column (2d) vector. This probably also solves your second issue, related to the depth of the result vector.

(I don't use sage, so I can't reproduce your error.)

Comment: Interesting. I tried your method on python-2.6 it works without any error. But in Sage-5.3, it always pops up error message:"     97         options = dict(ColPerm=permc_spec)
     98         return _superlu.gssv(N, A.nnz, A.data, A.indices, A.indptr, b, flag,
---> 99                              options=options)[0]
    100 
    101 def splu(A, permc_spec=None, diag_pivot_thresh=None,

ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array"